# Updating a related post's "post_modified" value

Tags: hooks

I have two custom post types; 'projects' and 'activities' - when an activity is created / updated, I want to update elements of the project - one of these elements is to update the 'post_modified' value (elsewhere in the site, I am ordering the project post type by 'modified' time so that the most recently worked on projects are given priority in the archives)

This is what I have currently:

```
// update project updated time on activity save
add_action('save_post_cpt_activities', 'update_project_update_time', 10, 1);

function update_project_update_time($post_id) {
  // get the associated project
  $project = get_field('project', $post_id);
  if( $project ) {
    $time = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id);
    // echo $time;
    // die();
    wp_update_post(
      [
        'ID'                => $project,
        'post_modified'     => $time,
        'post_modified_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

The hook triggers fine (the debugging 'die' echos the correct post date and I have tried echoing the response of wp_update_post (which returns the correct post ID) but this is where it gets confusing. The activity I am updating was posted yesterday and whenever this activity is updated, the project is updating with the current date / time rather than copying the post date / time from the activity.

Is there some element of

Answer (score 0):

Had a brainwave whilst typing up the question.. there are other actions that fire when a post is updated, such as [post_updated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) which naturally update the post_modified timestamp.

Instead I decided to save the activity's modified time as a meta value, and will sort on that instead and leave the post_modified functionality intact.

The trimmed down function:

```php
function update_project_update_time($post_id) {
  // get the associated project
  $project = get_field('project', $post_id);
  if( $project ) {
    $time = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id);
    update_post_meta($project, 'last_modified', $time);
  }
}
```